# Event in C# - Is it OOP?

Tags: c#, oop, events

Since I start using event in c# I always want to know if it's OOP oriented.

Let me explain. In Java, it had EventListner, Observer/Observable which object have to inherit to be able to fire an event or to listen to it . My point is, in Java, it have to be an object which have the responsibility to notify the subscriber or to do an action after being notify. In c#, all I see is :

```
public delegate void SomeHandler();
public event SomeHandler OnAction;

...
//somewhere in the firing class
OnAction();

...
//somewhere else in a subscriber class
_generateReport.ReportSubmited += someMethod;

private void someMethod()
{
//do some job
}
```

No class, only method and attribut...

So, is it OOP and if it is, how does it work?

Thanks !

Comment: What does it mean for something to be OOP?

Comment: I don't think you see that. You can't have a field of type `event` outside a class. Could you post a more complete example of what you see, please?

Comment: SomeHandler is actually a class. the delegate keyword creates it behind with some compiler magic. I'm pretty sure John Skeet will stay here soon riding his white horse tipping just form the top of his head all the IL involved and the compiler trickery.

Comment: @Markust - I think you mean [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: @Chris - Crap. The habit of tipping John with the H. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type responsible for holding a list of handlers is the `SomeHandler` type, which is a delegate type. You can build an instance of a delegate from an appropriate method, representing a call to that method... and you can combine delegates together to represent a sequence of calls.

Think of events as language/platform support for the observer pattern, basically.

You should be aware of what events and delegates are like under the hood - see my [article on them](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for some more details.

The non-OO part of this is that although *delegates* can be passed around like any other object, *events* can't :( You can use their reflection equivalent (`EventInfo`) but it's not quite the same thing...

Comment: I don't call the last part non-OO. Encapsulation is a core OOP principle, and events are just a form of that.

Comment: @Martinho: But the events themselves can't be used as objects, which can be a real pain in the neck. Look at what you have to do in order to subscribe to events in a general way in LINQ to Rx...

Comment: @Martinho: I think Jon's not complaining about the encapsulation, but about them not being first-class object. @Jon: Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

It is OOP- C# just hides the implementation details from you. `someMethod()` is called on the instance of the class, if it is an instance method, from which it was taken.

In Java, you have to manually inherit and fiddle around.

Answer (score 1):

In many scenarios,like when its required to have a loosely coupling relation between modules which are in different assemblies,its a very good idea to use delegates and events.So a class, by means of these kind of useful objects(I mean delegates and events),can invoke a method without having to know anything about its code,and in such a way we decouple the responsibilities of each class clearly.
lets assume we have two classes in completely different assemblies as follows:

```
        private Rectangle GetActiveWindowBounds(Func<IRunningAppActionResult> 
               methodOne , Func<IRunningAppActionResult>  methodTwo)
                 {
                  Task.Run(() => { return methodOne(); }).Wait();




 _clientAppRectangleBitmapHelper.GetBrowserActiveAreaByColor(Color.Red);
                      Task.Run(() =>  {return methodTwo();
                       }).Wait();
                        return _clientAppRectangle;
              }
```

and from other class that uses this class and want to make this class to obtain a rectangle,but does not want it to know how obtain an IRunningAppActionResult, we can use Func as follow:

```
     var browserRectangle = _browserWindowManager.GetActiveWindowBounds(
            () => this.SendActionWithResult(new 
                                 MakeBackgroundRedAction()),
                                         () => this.SendActionWithResult(new 
                  RevertBackgroundAction()));
```

Comment: more explanation

Answer (score 0):

`someMethod()` is declared private. It is a private member from a class, which is OOP

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing that contradicts with OOP. Event is just set of two methods that manipulate with delegate (in your case delegate itself if behind the scene). Delegate in turn is linked list of pairs of method reference and target of invocation.